# PhoneGap function 'Media' to play sound doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova

I have very simple code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function playAudio() {
// i try to specificate path to audio file different ways:
           var src ="/android_asset/www/track.mp3";
           //src = "http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3";
           var media = new Media(src, // success callback
                    function() {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
            // error callback
            function(err) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);
        });
           alert('sm'); // alert doesn't work -> so prev func 'new Media' doesn't work too
           media.play();

        }

    </script>
```

And call of this func is such:

```
<body onload="playAudio()">
```

I don't understand - why doesn't it work? Audio file is 'assets/www/track.mp3'

Comment: try this way `var src ="//android_asset//www/track.mp3";`

Comment: @Vigbyor, no, it doesn't work too(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand yet why, but when I try do work with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function playAudio(url) {
        // Play the audio file at url
        // http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3
        var my_media = new Media(url,
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
                alert("ok");
            },
            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
                alert("oops");
            }
        );
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }
    </script>
```

And called it in:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/track.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
```

Or when I call it this way:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
```

Only on simulator it work! But in web-browser it doesn't work still yet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
var src ="/android_asset/www/track.mp3";
```

JS don't know `/android_asset/`
Only JAVA know about this path only so either use java - JS injection or put this file inside www folder.

Comment: could you write ex of Java-JS injection? or if i put this file to another folder of project what should i put in 'var src' ?

Comment: put this file in www folder. then acces it directly by file name 
`var src ="track.mp3";`

Comment: for JAVA - JS injection there are so many tutorials for it.
all the plugins of phonegap use it.

Comment: my file is in folder 'assets/www'! folder 'www' in root catalog of project doesn't exist. Use of var src="track.mp3" doesn't work too in this case

Comment: see www folder have HTML+JS+CSS so it must follow the path accordingly you can test it on browser as well.

Comment: ohh you should check the path from your .html page to your .mp3 file

Comment: sorry that i don't understand what you say. i'm not good in english =\ in browser file playing when i use path 'file:///D:/android-workspace/Tetris_phoneGap/assets/www/track.mp3'. but in project it doesn't work =\\

Comment: ohh thats not my mean, i want to say there is a need to put the relative path of .mp3 file from your .html page. like if both are in equal directory then put like that `var src ="track.mp3";`

Comment: oh, ok, now i understand, buut.. my index.html page is in equal directory with track.mp3. They both are in 'assets/www' folder of project. And using var src='track.mp3' don't work

Comment: open this html page in browser and then check your link